Get a list of all dates between the earlier and later dates of a table [PowerBI]
I've got a table imported from a csv with multiple rows.
I've a column with dates, I need to get a list between the minimum and the maximum value of this.
I know that i can get the MIN and the MAX from the table, but hoy can i get a list of all dates between?

Where you need the list of date? in a table visual? In a separate table? or in the same table?

you can create a new table by using calendar function
table=calendar(min(date),max(date)

DAX Calendar
